# Custom tabBarViewController and viewController rotation

Tags: ios, objective-c

I use custom tabBarViewController as root viewcontroller which contain 6 navigation viewControllers. I have try to override the willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation method on rootviewcontroller and other viewcontrollers, I found that it can be called only on rootviewcontroller. but i need both to be called.

- ```
  (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
     duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
  ```

What can I do for this?

Thank you very much in advance.